# Квадратный блок, ширина которого зависит от количества текста в нем

Tags: html, css

У меня есть блок с текстом, количество текста в котором может меняться. Блок всегда должен быть квадратным и его ширина всегда должна быть минимальной, но чтобы вмещался текст. Подскажите как сделать такой блок(и можно ли такое сделать вообще?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.quadratish {
  padding: 1em;
  background: #CCC;
  display: inline-block;
}

.quadratish::before {
  content: " ";
  padding-top: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class=quadratish>some random text</div>
<div class=quadratish>some random text a bit longer</div>
```